# Iframes in iOS, fixed positioning and scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iframe, scroll

I have a base html file that holds an iFrame that is supposed to work as a "webview". This iframe should have the exact area of the mobile screen area, but as the iOS frames expand to its content, any absolut positioned content gets weird. I was able to workaround it with a (somewhat clunky) solution making the html of the frame with a fixed height, and putting the body with fixed position and overflow:auto.

(The fixed position prevented the flicker on scroll).

The problem is: Now anything that was on the frame listening for window.scroll() won't work anymore as, well, the window isn't scrolling anymore. :)

I wanted to make something like this:

Listen for the $('body').scroll event and then fake a trigger on the $(window).scroll event with the body scrollLeft/scrollTop. Is there anyway to achieve this, without actually scrolling the window (which is impossible in my scenario)?

My test files are these:

Base html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<style>
    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    iframe {
        position: relative;
        height:500px;
        border:none;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="teste2.html" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And the iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<style>
    html {
        overflow:auto;
        height:500px;
    }
    body {
        position:fixed;
        overflow:auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        width:100vw;
        height:500px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;    
    }
    .wrapper {
        height:2000px;
        background:green;
    }
    .footer {
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        height:50px;
        background:red;
        z-index:20;
    }
</style>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('.wrapper').css('background','blue');

        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) { 
                $('.wrapper').css('background','yellow');
            }
        });     
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for any help. If you need anymore information, please help me describe the issue a little better.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, not yet. We ended up deciding not to use the iframe as a webview for the iOS app. :/